# BlackBerry Playbook MSSQL connection approach

Tags: sql-server, apache-flex, blackberry, flash-builder, blackberry-webworks

**Scenario**

Company has ordered a large amount of PlayBooks for our technicians to service our goods. We currently have a webportal that uses PHP to pull data from our SQL Server 2008R and display it to our clients via browser.

**Purpose**

The PlayBooks are meant to acquire e-signatures and text data and uploaded to our MS-SQL 2008R server

**Problem**

After doing a large amount of research, I found out that the playbook has two suitable ways for application development in our company: **WebWorks** or **Adobe AIR (Flash Builder)**

To my understanding, if I choose to use WebWorks, I need some sort of middle-ware (like our webportal) to connect to our SQL Server. This poses a problem as it introduces a source of error and our webportal is prone to downtime or being slow. This is a very unattractive feature and the company would like to avoid it at all costs

**Question**

If I choose to purchase Adobe Flash Builder, by using whatever tools it offer will it guarantee me a direct connection to our SQL Server 2008R without the need to go through any middle-ware?

Or is there an alternative way altogether?

Comment: Build a web application instead of a native Playbook app.

Comment: Unfortunately the task I was given enforces me to create a native Playbook app, I have decided on giving their Adobe AIR SDK a try.

Comment: Do you have the option to use a REST API to access Web Services you host? With this you could use the AIR SDK to make requests/posts to the server and do all the MS SQL Server code in PHP (or any other language on your server)